# How to: Typescript and knockout return function

Tags: jquery, typescript

I have a javascript that needs to be translated to Typescript. It uses knockout objects as entry parameters.

typescript imports i use:

```
import $ = require("jquery");
import ko = require("knockout");
```

javascript for translation:

```
var kFunc = function(stringParam) {
    return function(fn, element, viewModel) {
        var result = fn(element, viewModel);
        return result;
    }
}
```

What would the typescript for this be?

Comment: Are you sure that is only javascript? Import keyword is not yet supported without transpilers.

Comment: sorry i was supposed to divide it in two parts import is the starter for the typescript.. will edit in a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics is your friend. You can add more explicit type information.

```
var kFunc = function<TElement, TViewMdel, TResult>(stringParam: string) : (fn:((element:TElement, viewModel:TViewMdel)=>TResult), element:TElement, viewModel:TViewMdel) => TResult {
    return function(fn, element: TElement, viewModel: TViewMdel) {

        var result = fn(element, viewModel);
        return result;
    };
};
```

And usage :

```
var s2:boolean= true;
var s:string = "";
var m:boolean = true;
var r:string = kFunc<string, boolean, string>("")((ss, mm) => m===true?ss:"", s, m);
var r2:string = kFunc<string, boolean, string>("")((ss, mm) => m===true?ss:"", s2, m); // error on s2

function tt (a:boolean, b:string):string { return "result"}
var r3:string = kFunc<string, boolean, string>("")(tt, s, m); // error on tt
```